# User accounts without ASP.net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am adding authentication to an existing .net MVC project that is mostly APIs with a SPA interface. I don't want to hook up the whole ASP.net identity library for something as small as this project. I just want simple accounts with `name`, `email`, and `password`, and an API method to `register()`, `login()`, and `logout()`. **What's the simplest way of implementing bearer token authentication without ASP.net identity?**

Comment: Probably Owin/Katana and a middleware.

Comment: @BradChristie I took your advice and it seems like OWIN is the way to go. I'll post my solution shortly.

Answer (score 3):

I took @BradChristie's advice and created a super simple OWIN authentication layer.

I've posted all of the essential files, install instructions, and test instructions to a separate [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/JustMaier/b8a519f0e57a0a53db64).

Comment: Great job on the middleware. ;-)

Comment: @JustMaier: Hey, this may seem exactly what I need: I'm not using asp.net identity, but the old aspnet_membership tables. I want my existing users to be able to login with their username/password (which are stored in my DB) via oAuth...is that what your code does?

Comment: Hey @Flo, you could modify it to work with existing membership tables, you would just need to modify the verification bit in `Helpers_SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.cs`

Comment: @JustMaier Ah, perfect! Thanks for getting back to me, I'll give that a shot, to be sure: you code essentially functions as an oAuth authorization server right?

Comment: @Flo thats right. You'll be able to hit /token with a username/password and it will return a bearer token that you can then use to authorize going forward.

Comment: @JustMaier Thanks man, your code is (probably) gonna be a life saver for my project :)